# Wrong simplification of $2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to do the exercise 01, chapter 02 of the book: Algorithm Design [Kleinberg _ Tardos] - publication version 03 of the book

I need to manipulate $2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}$, what I did was:

1. $2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}$
2. $2^{\frac{1}{2}\log_2n}\impliedby$ Log property where $\log_b(n^a)=a\log_bn$
3. $n^{\frac{1}{2}\log_22}\impliedby$ Log property where $a^{\log_bc}=c^{\log_ba}$
4. $n^{\frac{1}{2}}\impliedby\log_22=1$

I don't know the correct answer. Moreover I know that the correct answer is **smaller** than $n^\frac{1}{3}$, and $n^\frac{1}{2}$is not smaller than $n^\frac{1}{3}$, so I messed up somewhere but I cannot find.

Comment: Please use mathjax. This is rather hard to read.

Comment: Also, where did this come from? Take a [tour] on how to ask a good question.

Comment: done! Thanks for the feedbacks

Comment: Try putting $n$ with some values to check which step(s) went wrong?

Comment: Many Thanks Catarina...

Comment: $\sqrt {\log _2 n}  \ne \log _2 (\sqrt n )$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression like $2^{\sqrt{\log_2 n}}$ does *not* simplify to anything nicer.

First, the problem with the attempt in the question is that there is no rule to simplify $(\log x)^k$. We can simplify $\log(x^k)$ to $k \log x$, but there's nothing to be done when we *first* take the logarithm and *then* raise the result to a power. In particular, $\sqrt{\log_2 n} \ne \frac12 \log_2 n$. (To make this more obvious, let $y = \log_2 n$; then you are trying to simplify $\sqrt{y}$ to $\frac12 y$.)

We can make some comparisons between $2^{\sqrt{\log_2 n}}$ and other functions in terms of growth rates. More precisely:

- For all $k>0$, no matter how large, $2^{\sqrt{\log_2 n}}$ grows more slowly than $n^{1/k}$: for large enough $n$ (depending on $k$), we have $2^{\sqrt{\log_2 n}} < n^{1/k}$. To see this, take the logarithm of both sides: we get $\sqrt{\log_2 n}$ on one side and $\frac1k \log_2 n$ on the other. In terms of $y = \log_2 n$ again, $\sqrt y$ will be less than $y/k$ provided $y > k^2$; therefore $2^{\sqrt{\log_2 n}} < n^{1/k}$ provided $n > 2^{k^2}$.
- For all $k>0$, no matter how large, $2^{\sqrt{\log_2 n}}$ grows more quickly than $(\log_2 n)^k$. To see this, once again, take the logarithm of both sides: now we are comparing $\sqrt{\log_2 n}$ to $k \log_2 \log_2 n$, or in terms of $y = \log_2 n$, we are comparing $\sqrt{y}$ to $k \log_2 y$.

Comment: Oh, I see! Based on your answer, to try to visualise better, I'm trying to multiply by ${\log_2n}$ on both sides, so ${\log_2n}$*x = ${\log_2n}$* $2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}$. I arrived on ${\log_2n}$*x = ${\log_2n}$*${\sqrt{n}}$, which is basically the same I found before, there is still an error somewhere. I did now the following: 1) ${\log_2n}$* $2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}$ . Then 2) ${\log_2n}$* ${\sqrt{2^\log_2n}}$ .  Then 3) ${\log_2n}$* ${\sqrt{n^\log_22}}$ . Then 4) ${\log_2n}$*${\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Replacing $2^{\sqrt y}$ by $\sqrt{2^y}$ is also incorrect!

Comment: So how can ${\log_2n}$* $2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}$ be (log_2n)^1/2 ? I put on Wolfram Alpha and I got the answer like this, but I just cannot arrive there :(

Comment: "does not simplify to anything nicer", this sounds too categorical, especially since nicer is a subjective word. How can we prove it? Perhaps someone will find something "nicer" in some sense.

Comment: Those two expressions are not equal, and my best guess is that you typed something into Wolfram Alpha that didn't mean what you thought it meant. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Log%5B2%2Cn%5D*2%5ESqrt%5BLog%5B2%2Cn%5D%5D) is my attempt at entering it into Wolfram Alpha, and it doesn't simplify.

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira Can you edit your question to include your new attempt and the WolframAlpha link?

Comment: @zkutch Though "nicer" is somewhat subjective, I think that the categorical statement is the best advice for someone who struggles working with this expression. Someone that can put into a different situationally more useful form in a special circumstance does not need my answer.